# SQL to Entity Framework Using "In"

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I've got an ASP.NET MVC application using EF in C#. I can write and run my query correctly in SQL Server. In EF, I'm not sure how to accomplish the same thing.

Tables A, B and C. C references B which References A.

The query looks like this:

```
Select * 
From C
Where C.bID in (Select B.bID 
                From B
                Where B.aID = '<unique Key In A>')
```

The sub-query returns multiple B keys. Which then pass it through and look up the ID's in C. In short I'm looking up all data in C related to a key in A.

I just don't know how to put that into EF language. Or if it's even possible. The `IN` operator is what's throwing me on the conversion.

Example:

```
  var exampleList = _context.C
                        .Where(l => l.bId in (_context.B
                        .Where(p => p.aId = keyInA)));
```

"in" doesn't work here. Obviously. After I wrote this post I made sure of it.

Note: A:B has a 1:Many relation. B:C has a 1 to many relation. All IDs and keys are GUIDs

Comment: you need to use Contains()

Comment: You could test it with `_context.C.Where(l => _context.B.Where(p => p.aId = keyInA).Select(p => p.bId).Contains(l.bId))`

Comment: Fantastic suggestion as far as i can see.. everything was going smoothly. I should have said, all Key's and ID's are GUIDs. I'm getting "IQueryable<Guid>' does not contain a definition for "'Contains'..." goes on to say the overload need a receiver. Added that info to the original question in bold so it isn't missed.

Comment: @Core Can you verify your using statements and the data types for `p.bId` and `l.bId`? There error you are describing can happen when the data types don't match or if you do not have `using System.Linq`.

Comment: Use navigation properties: `Where(c => c.B.aID == '<unique Key In A>')`.

Comment: GertArnold "c." is in the context of "C" table. Using "c.B" there is no context for accessing the B table within "c". It didn't work. It's possible my knowledge isn't enough to leverage the statement.  @jwatts1980 All data types here are the same unless otherwise specified: All are "uniqueidentifier" in SQL server. All are PK or FK's. All were scaffold built in VS and defined as "public Guid aId { get; set: }" within the model views. (aId, bId, cId). EXCEPT.. the FK relation in C is nullable. Basically the record can exist before the A > B data is determined and can be assigned to C.

Comment: @jwatts1980 Forgot, yes, i am using System.Linq. Ok, looking at it, the .Contains is obviously applying to the C context. I remove the .Contains and close the statement, and a new issue appears. "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.Iqueryable<System.Guid' to 'bool'"  -- "Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type."   That's with "==". Because i'm stumped i used a single equal. This line  ".Where(p => p.aId = keyInA)"   shows "Cannot convert System.Type.Guid to 'bool'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set up the navigation property between C & B, and between A & B. This is pretty much the whole point of using Entity Framework rather than just an alternative to ADO and SQL queries.

C contains a BId, so set up a B navigation property:

```
public class C
{
    public int CId { get; set; } 
    [ForeignKey("B")]
    public int BId { get; set; }
    public virtual B B { get; set; }
}
```

B contains an AId, so similar:

```
public class B
{ 
    public int BId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("A")]
    public int AId { get; set; }
    public virtual A A { get; set; }
}
```

Now, to write your query:

```
var cs = context.Cs.Where(x => x.B.AId == id);
```

or

```
var cs = context.Cs.Where(x => x.B.A.AId == id); // can filter on other "A" fields this way.
```

I mean, to avoid the use of navigation properties, you may as well just write Sprocs and use ADO.  It is possible in cases where you have unrelated tables or absolutely need to avoid a navigation property. Use a `Join` between context.Cs and context.Bs:

```
var cs = context.Cs.Join(context.Bs, c => c.BId, b => b.BId, (c, b) => new { C = c, AId = b.AId })
                .Where(x => x.AId == aid)
                .Select(x => x.C);
```

IMO seriously ugly working with joins in EF, but sometimes necessary. If you can use a navigation property I'd highly recommend it over using something like that regularly.

Comment: While this, technically worked and will market it as the "answer".. I didn't have to use it. The project scaffold created a hash set off the foreign keys in each of the 3 data models. IF children exist for the specific record, they're already populated within the hash set! The data literally already exists and was present. Just buried in a subset of data. Example: Foreach A.B (assuming A.B has children FK'd) spin through those records. Kinda scary. That's a lot of data to be skimming in a subset. EDIT: It IS set up the way you suggested.